# How to split a php array into several parts to insert them in csv column names?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I wrote a code that allows me to read an excel file, transform it into csv and make modifications on it. I add at the end of this file 10 columns, the problem is that the name of the columns is added at once with "PICT1;PICT2; PICT3;PICT4;..." in only one column at the end of the 10. I would like each column to be called PICT1, PICT2, PICT3... How do I do this?

Currently I have this:
[image]

I would like that:

[image]

```
<?php
    


    function multiSplit($string)
        {
            $output = array();
            $cols = explode(",", $string);

        foreach ($cols as $col)
        {
            $dashcols = explode("-", $col);
            $output[] = $dashcols[0];
        }
        
        return $output;
      }


//Modifications on csv file
$delimiter = $delimiterpost;
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        
        //Add columns at the end
        $data['Pictures Names'] = (!empty($data[4]) ? ($data[7] ?: '') . "_" . $data[4] . '.jpg' : ''); 
        $data['Color-Description'] = (!empty($data[3]) ? (ltrim($data[4], '0') ?: '') . "-" . $data[3] : '');  
            
        $out = multiSplit($data[23]);
        
        $data['PICT1'] = $out[0];
        $data['PICT2'] = $out[1];   
        $data['PICT3'] = $out[2];  
        $data['PICT4'] = $out[3];  
        $data['PICT5'] = $out[4]; 
        $data['PICT6'] = $out[5]; 
        $data['PICT7'] = $out[6];  
        $data['PICT8'] = $out[7];
        $data['PICT9'] = $out[8]; 
        $data['PICT10'] = $out[9];
                
        // Delete three columns
        unset($data[1]);
        unset($data[2]);
    unset($data[3]);

        //Modifications on the fourth line
        if ($row == 4) 
        {
               //All uppercase
               $data = array_map('strtoupper', $data);  
               $data = str_replace(' *', '', $data);
               $data = str_replace('/', '', $data);
               //Replacement of spaces by an underscore
               $data = str_replace(' ', '_', $data);
               $data = str_replace('__', '_', $data);
               //Replacement name by another name
               $data = str_replace('STYLE_COLOR.JPG', 'PICT', $data);
               $data = str_replace('COLOR-DESCRIPTION', 'COLOR_DESCRIPTION', $data);
               
                array_filter($data, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; });

                for ( $i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
                    $data[] = "PICT$i";
                }                                          
        }   
        

         if ($data[22])          
        {
            $data = str_replace(',', '§- ', $data);
                    
        }

            $csv_data[] = $data; 
                              
        $row++;      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$csv_data = array_slice($csv_data, 3); // this will remove first three elements
array_pop($csv_data);// this will remove last element from array


if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'w')) !== FALSE) {    
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$data[] ='PICT1'.$delimiter.'PICT2'.$delimiter.'PICT3'.$delimiter.'PICT4'.$delimiter.'PICT5'.$delimiter.'PICT6'.$delimiter.'PICT7'.$delimiter.'PICT8'.$delimiter.'PICT9'.$delimiter.'PICT10';
```

With a loop that creates the additional array items

```
// clean out any empty titles as there appear to be some at the end of the array
array_filter($data, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; });

for ( $i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
    $data[] = "PICT$i";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but the columns are always at the end after the 10, not after COLOR_DESCRIPTION

Comment: Oh, your data has me a little confused and as you are using the old now defunct version of PHPExcel I cannot test it. Could it be that yo just need to move it so it places the column labels in the right place

Comment: I would have to put it in the place of all the $data['PICT1'] = $out [0]?

Comment: Surely this is adding column titles, that only gets dont once

Comment: Yes what I want is to add the title to the 10 columns I add at the end of my file

Comment: So where is this adding these 10 titles? I didnt understand what you ment by `after the 10`

Comment: I just added a screenshot, with the modification you made I have my csv file that comes out like this. And I would like as on the second screenshot me

Comment: Well my code will add to the end of the array. Not sure why or how the array has 8 blank occurances at the end of it before this is run?

Comment: The occurrences of blanks are columns that are filled in the file, I add them with the 10 "$data['PICT1'] = $out[0];", "$data['PICT2'] = $out[1];",... in my code. It is these columns that I would like them to have the title that is added at the end

Comment: Added some code to remove empty occurances from your array, does that improve the result, or cause other issues?

Comment: When I add your lines instead of my old one I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in ".

Comment: DUHhhhhh Missed the semi colon from the end of the new line :)

Comment: Rah... I have the same problem as before with this modification

Comment: OK I am going to brave your data and have a proper look at this, may take me a little while

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, if you need other things to understand please tell me

Comment: I think you need to look closer at the `solidpepper_file.csv` It does not look like your code appears to think it does. As I dont really know what you are trying to achieve I am going to call it a day now.

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, after several hours of reflection I managed to correct my mistake and find out where it came from!